# Is it possible to authenticate to CosmosDB using a service principal with the Java Azure SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is it possible to authenticate to CosmosDB using a service principal with the Java Azure SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Cosmos Db does not support RBAC for data operations:

  [Role-based access control in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/role-based-access-control)

  > RBAC support in Azure Cosmos DB applies to control plane operations only. Data plane operations are secured using master keys or resource tokens. To learn more, see [Secure access to data in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data).
- You need to use master keys or resource tokens to access Cosmos Db:

  [Secure access to data in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data)
- You can use Key Vault to store and access your Cosmos Db keys:

  [Secure Azure Cosmos keys using Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/access-secrets-from-keyvault).